# touch and drop in WP7 / XNA?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0, windows-phone-7

I want to create a drawing based application using touch and drop in which there would be a canvas on which shapes are dropped

Can any one guide me how can i achieve this touch and drop toolbox and which would 
be better for this? windows phone or xna game studio

Comment: It depends on various features you might want, but I would say Silverlight is going to be easier. Just need to handle the touch events and place the shapes on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using silverlight.  Here's a good place to start: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/gestures